# How to copy month/year in two columns of different workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

From the Worksheet "Exclusive" (Workbook "Time.xlsx"), I want to copy all the values (String, Integer) within the range B1 to E500 into the Worksheet "ValueTime" of another Workbook "Ontime.xlsm".

I did:

```
Workbooks("Time.xlsx").Worksheets("Time").Range("B1:B500, E1:E500").Copy
```

This error follows:

> -2147352565(8002000b) unknown name

I tried to solve this problem as follows:

```vb
Dim intcounter As Integer Dim strTransport As Integer
For intcounter = 1 To 255
    If Cells("B1:B500, E1:E500", intcounter <> "") Then strTransport = Left(Cells("B1:B500, E1:E500", intcounter), 255) 
        Exit For
    End If
Next intcounter
```

The same error follows.

I want to automatically delete/crop out the last 255 characters (on another website someone also had the same problem and come to the conclusion that this error appears because 255 characters are too many) but it would be great if every value can be copied and displayed.

I also want to copy month and year of Workbook Time into the Worksheet "ValueTime" of the Workbook OnTime.
Month and year should be copied in two columns

I did:

```vb
Range("E1").Value  = "Month"
Range("F1").Value = "Year"
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Format(Range("E1").Value, "mmmm")
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Format(Range("F1").Value, "yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't your very first line be:

```
Workbooks("Time.xlsx").Worksheets("Exclusive").Range("B1:E500").Copy
```

Since you said you're copying from the sheet "Exclusive"? Unknown name makes sense if you don't have a worksheet called "Time". If your range is B1 to E500, no need to separate it, just B1:E500 will do. How you formulated it, it would only select the B1 to B500 and E1 to E500 cells.

To copy this to the corresponding sheet:

```
Workbooks("Time.xlsx").Worksheets("Exclusive").Range("B1:E500").Copy: Workbooks("Ontime.xlsm").Worksheets("ValueTime").Range("A1") 'assuming you don't have anything in A-column yet since you start your month in E
```

For the month/year, it depends where your month/year comes from. Is it a single date in your OnTime? I would've asked in comment first but I'm not allowed yet.

EDIT:

```
Workbooks("Time.xlsx").Worksheets("Exclusive").Range("F2:F500").Copy Destination:= Workbooks("Ontime.xlsm").Worksheets("ValueTime").Range("E1") 'Since you're putting "Month" and "Year" as your headers, I hope your values in "Exclusive" also start in the second row
Workbooks("Ontime.xlsm").Worksheets("ValueTime").Range("E2:E500").Format = "mmmm"
Workbooks("Time.xlsx").Worksheets("Exclusive").Range("F1:F500").Copy Destination:= Workbooks("Ontime.xlsm").Worksheets("ValueTime").Range("F1")
Workbooks("Ontime.xlsm").Worksheets("ValueTime").Range("F2:F500").Format = "yyyy"
```

So to Format, copy values first, format after. Notice that the value of the date remains so you could technically copy the E-column from your Valuetime to F as well even after having formatted it to "mmmm".
In hindsight, setting the workbooks/worksheets to variables would've been a lot easier to read/write but since you're starting out, I didn't want to overwhelm you.

Comment: First, thank you for answering! You are right, Exclusive is the right sheet name, I just have typed the wrong name (my fault!). I think I solved the problem. I forgot to activate the Sheet now I can run my code :-) but I still have the problem with the date. Month and year is the "today's date". I export the actual data from an external database and convert it to excel to the Workbook "Time.xlsx". and the date is in the number format "day-month-year". But Month should be displayed as String or Text and year as number.

Comment: Edited to include your date-formatting. Hope it's clear this way and you understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these general steps to copy the month/year from one workbook to another:

Open both workbooks in Microsoft Excel.

In the source workbook, select the column containing the month/year data that you want to copy.

Press "Ctrl + C" or right-click and select "Copy" to copy the data.

Switch to the destination workbook.

Select the cell where you want to paste the data.

Right-click the cell and select "Paste Special" from the menu.

In the "Paste Special" dialog box, select "Values" and click "OK".

The month/year data should now be copied over to the destination workbook.

Note: If the two workbooks have different formats or layouts, you may need to adjust the cell references or format the data after pasting it into the destination workbook.